# Multiple views with shadow and rotation becomes very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make multiple stacks of uiview's. Each of those UIView's with a shadow, slight rotation and scale. As a test I'm making 10 stack's of 10 views. Drawing all this is very slow.. Is there a good way to optimise this? I tried making the shadow and background from a image but that was ugly and equally as slow. I put these stacks in a UIScrollView

```
   for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        UIView *stack = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i * 106), (k * 106), 110, 110)];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            CardView *cardView = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

            //cardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"card_background.png"]];

            cardView.layer.shadowOffset     = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
            cardView.layer.shadowOpacity    = 0.3f;
            cardView.layer.shadowPath       = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, cardView.layer.bounds.size}].CGPath; // Set shadow path, without this the performance is *really* bad
            cardView.transform              = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(((arc4random() % 20) - 10.0f) / 100.0f);
            cardView.transform              = CGAffineTransformScale(cardView.transform, 0.35, 0.35);
            cardView.layer.shouldRasterize  = YES;
            cardView.layer.rasterizationScale = 0.5;

            cardView.center = CGPointMake(55, 55);

            [stack addSubview:cardView];
        }

        [_backgroundView addSubview:stack];
    }

}
```

Edit 1; Tried some stuff, disabling rasterzation isn't helping much, disabling the shadow doesn't help much either, rotation and scaling are recourse intensive with this much uiview's too. Would async drawing (one stack at the time) be an option?

Edit 2; Guess making 100 UIView's is just slow anyway. I'll report back if I've found a better (I guess async or something like that) solution

Answer (score 1):

Are you using these images in some sort of animation? If not you can try turning off rasterizing to increase performance.

```
cardView.layer.shouldRasterize  = NO;
```

Comment: Unfortionally it doesn't help much, the rotation and scaling makes it very slow too.

Answer (score 1):

Shadows are very computationally intensive. If `shouldRasterize` doesn't do it, make a `UIImage` for the shadow, and if your views can change size, load the image with `resizableImageWithCapInsets`.

Comment: Yeah, even without shouldRasterize it's very slow. I thought about making the stacks one image, stack and all. But eventually I want to make a animation in which the stack 'unfolds' so that wouldn't be an option. Maybe I'll look into the image option again

Even without the shadow it's slow, because of the rotation and scale... Hmm